# Nodejs + Expressjs + EJS + Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am new to the Nodejs and mongodb and trying to Insert the data into database and getting the 404 while submitting the form. Not sure what is wrong in the code. Any help would be appreciated. This is my code as below.

App.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongo = require('mongodb');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var restaurant = require('./routes/restaurant');
var shopping = require('./routes/shopping');
var hotel = require('./routes/hotel');
var aboutus = require('./routes/about');
var event = require('./routes/event');
var admin = require('./routes/admin');



var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/restaurant',restaurant);
app.use('/shop',shopping);
app.use('/hotel',hotel);
app.use('/about',aboutus);
app.use('/event',event);
app.use('/admin',admin);
app.use('/insert',admin);
app.use('/get-data',admin);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Page Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**admin.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/aligarhcity';

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('admin', { title: 'Aligarh City'});
});

//READ THE DATA FROM DATABASE
router.get('/get-data', function(req,res,next){
    var resultArray = [];
    mongoClient.connect(url,function (err,db) {
    assert.equal(null,err);
    var cursor = db.collection('shopping').find();
    cursor.forEach(function(doc,err){
        assert.equal(null,err);
        resultArray.push(doc);
    },function () {
        db.close();
        res.render('/admin',{item:resultArray});
    });
});
});

//iNSERT THE DATA IN THE DATABASE
router.post('/insert', function(req,res,next){
    var shop = {
     shop_name:req.body.shop_name,
     shop_address:req.body.shop_address,
     shop_city:req.body.shop_city,
     shop_zip:req.body.shop_zip,
     shop_email:req.body.shop_email,
     shop_phone:req.body.shop_phone,
     shop_rating_5: '10',
     shop_rating_4: '10',
     shop_rating_3: '10',
     shop_rating_2: '10',
     shop_rating_1: '10'
 };
 console.log(shop_name,shop_city,shop_address,shop_zip,shop_email,shop_phone);
 mongoClient.connect(url,function (err,db) {
     assert.equal(null,err);
     db.collection('shopping').insertOne(shop,function (err, result) {
        assert.equal(null,err);
        console.log('Item Inserted Successfully');
        db.close();
     });
 });
 res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Admin.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%=title%></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>
<body bgcolor="White" height="100%">
<table height="100%" width="100%" border=0>
    <tr width="100%">
        <td width="100%" height="100%">
            <table width="100%" height="100%"  background="/images/city.gif" border=0>
                <tr width="100%" height="100%">
                    <td width="100%" height="100%">
                        <% include template/header.ejs%>
                        <h1 align="center"><img src="/images/aligarh.png"  height="450" width="1000"></h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr width="100%">
        <td width="100%">
            <div>
            <form action="/insert" method="post">
                <table width="30%" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="shop_name">Shop Name:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <input type="text" id="shop_name" name="shop_name" placeholder="Enter your shop name" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="shop_address">Shop Address</label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <input type="text" id="shop_address" name="shop_address" placeholder="Enter your shop address" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="shop_city">Shop City</label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <input type="text" id="shop_city" name="shop_city" placeholder="Enter your shop city" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="shop_zip">Shop Zip</label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <input type="text" id="shop_zip" name="shop_zip" placeholder="Enter your shop zip" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="shop_email">Shop Email</label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <input type="text" id="shop_email" name="shop_email" placeholder="Enter your shop email" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="shop_phone">Shop Phone</label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <input type="text" id="shop_phone" name="shop_phone" placeholder="Enter your shop phone" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/get-data"> Load Data</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       <%
                        var item=[];
                        item.forEach(function (items) { %>
                        <li>
                            <%=items.shop_name%> <br>
                            <%=items.shop_address%> <br>
                            <%=items.shop_zip%>
                        </li>

                       <% })
                        %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Route problem -  check request methods on a route (post or get).

Comment: can you look into the code and explain

Comment: which url you are submitting form ?

Comment: on submit it uses /insert

Comment: have you tried /insert/insert ?

Comment: insert/insert while routing or in ejs ?

Comment: on submit use /insert/insert

Comment: I think it worked using /admin/insert in the EJS file. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

404 is mainly from server, check your express implementation, routes which you trying to access is implemented in code or not

Comment: The given code is not enough to check with your problems. As per code says following routes are only allowed
`app.use('/', index);
app.use('/restaurant',restaurant);
app.use('/shop',shopping);
app.use('/hotel',hotel);
app.use('/about',aboutus);
app.use('/event',event);
app.use('/admin',admin);
app.use('/insert',admin);
app.use('/get-data',admin);`
But, for verifying the whole flow this code is not enough. I dont know in some other submodules throwing error or not
Need to check full source

Comment: i am just using the admin link for the problem. rest all works fine. from my root page i click on admin link and then the admin.ejs gets loaded. post load i m just adding the details in the form and clcking on submit button which goes to /insert as per the action tag in the form and gives me 404. in my app.js i am routing the /insert to admin page again